# Audio stopped working Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I installed 19.04 earlier today and spent an hour trying to get audio working. Then audio finally started working after I plugged the speakers into a different spot in the back of my computer.

Then about an hour ago, after audio was working great, everything got quiet and stopped working. I have no idea why this is and don't know how to troubleshoot because this is my first day using linux.

[image]

[image]
[image]

It's very strange that there is an "Auto-Mute Mode" in alsamixer that seems to be enabled.

I am sorry, I don't know what I should be looking for or how to diagnose the problem and nothing I have found on the internet has helped so far. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try reinstalling ALSA and PulseAudio manually. That must be fix the problem for you. Enter the following commands on a terminal:

```
sudo apt remove --purge alsa-base
sudo apt remove --purge pulseaudio
sudo apt install alsa-base
sudo apt install pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Comment: it worked after I did what you suggested and restarted, thank you

Comment: Upgraded 18 to 19. Sound's gone. Applied all above and problem has gone.

Comment: this helped me even on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: If you are using ubuntu-gnome-desktop, like I do, you also need to reinstall `libcanberra-pulse`, otherwise the 'test speakers' functionality in gnome-control-centrum will not work, which will cause even more confusion.

I think in my case reinstalling alsa and pulse wasn't needed; I probably needed to poweroff and poweron again, instead of rebooting.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I got: gsd-media-keys[2466]: Unable to get default sink and gsd-media-keys[2466]: Unable to get default source errors in my syslog.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have enough points yety to comment... have your tried this one? Sometimes my laptop audio goes off and this does the trick

```
pulseaudio -k
```

From [`man pulseaudio`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/pulseaudio.1.html#options):

> `-k` | `--kill` Kill an already running PulseAudio daemon of the calling user (Equivalent to sending a SIGTERM).

Answer (score 3):

This problem has been going around a while. I have a ASUS UX433FN with a Realtek ALC294 chip. From [other threads](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1784485) it sounds like this issue (for dual-boot PC's) seems to be a result of Windows 10's fast boot behavior. I've disabled this feature in Windows 10, doing a full shutdown, and this has seem to fix my problem. Not sure if it's a permanent fix however.

[How to disable fast boot on Windows 10](https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10)

Comment: It worked for me. I have a Windows 10 dual boot and my audio would play for only about a second and then fade out, this fixed that.

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper glad to hear it fixed your issue. Would you mind sharing what PC you’re using?

Comment: It turns out that it was just the full shutdown that solves the issue. Even with FastBoot **disabled** restarting from Windows causes the sound issues. I'm using an ASUS ZenBook UX533FN

Comment: I upgraded my Ubuntu kernel to the most recent 5.4.0 aswell.

Comment: I can't express how happy I am i found this answer, thank you so much @Jon as the last 2 days have been extremely frustrating for me, trying to debug this problem. I read all of the pulseaudio + alsa troubleshooting guides, as well as kernel bug reports. Nothing worked, not even reinstalling Ubuntu or upgrading to newer kernels.

My system:  ASUS ZenBook UX334FLC / Ubuntu Focal (20.04) GNU/Linux Kernel: 5.7.9-050709  / Win 10

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the reinstall-PulseAudio-alsa suggestions but finally was able to get mine (a fresh install of 19.10) to work by installing the Gnome Extension ["Sound Input & Output Device Chooser"](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/906/sound-output-device-chooser/).

With that extension you get a drop-down list of places for the speakers. When I picked the one into which the speaker was plugged, I got sound.

Note, my system is a build with no internal speaker and I had to do this the last time I did a clean install and almost every time since I got rid of Windows on this machine and went to Ubuntu. (However, a clean install of Cinnamon Mint did not give me this issue, if I remember correctly that is.)