# No audio in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa, pavucontrol

There is no audio output from my earphone that is connected to the monitor. I tested the earphone with another laptop and it is working fine.

I tried the following solution from similar questions but the issue still persist:

1. [No sound in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046114/no-sound-in-ubuntu-18-04)

`killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*`

It returned 21 but sound is still unavailable.

2. [No sound in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS after upgrade from 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029403/no-sound-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-after-upgrade-from-16-04-lts)

`killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*`

3. [HDMI sound not working after upgrading to 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230002/hdmi-sound-not-working-after-upgrading-to-20-04)

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse/
reboot
```

4. [Audio stopped working Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155111/audio-stopped-working-ubuntu-19-04)

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base
    
sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
    
sudo apt-get install alsa-base
    
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
    
sudo alsa force-reload
```

5. `sudo alsamixer`
   Then F6 to select sound card and change the setting then reboot.

The Playback and Output Devices of pavucontrol both are using HDMI/Display Port 2 and the audio bar is fluctuating since I have YouTube running but no audio output at all. The following is the snapshot of my pavucontrol:

[image: pavucontrol snapshot]

[image]

Comment: What computer are you using?
I had a similar issue with an acer laptop of mine.

Comment: @One_Sleeve It is a custom PC that I built. In the end, I reinstalled Ubuntu,

Answer (score 1):

have you tried,

```
sudo alsamixer
```

and then unmute (Press m and up arrow to increase volume) the necessary things and reboot.

Comment: Yes, I did that too. F6 to select sound card and change the setting then reboot.